# pdf of conditional order statistic

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that I'm drawing random variables from a standard uniform distribution.

If there are n draws, then the maximum order statistic is distributed according to a $\beta(n,1)$ distribution.  Suppose however that I now know that the maximum order statistic is greater than some threshold x. I can't determine the distribution for the max order statistic conditional on it being greater than x.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if a random variable $Y$ has density $f_Y$, then if you know $Y>a$, then you simply truncate and scale the associated distribution:

$$f_{Y|Y>a}(y)=\frac{f_Y(y)}{1-F_Y(a)}\mathbf{1}_{>a}(y)$$